# Dynamically call functions in Python based on Class name

Tags: python

I have a Python app in which I'm trying to dynamically call functions in classes based on the school name.  The schools are in individual modules in the /schools directory:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.Schools = []
    self.Students = []

def Load_Selected_Schools(self):
    files = glob.glob('schools/*.py')
    for f in files:          
        self.Schools.append(self.Load_School(f))

def Load_School(self, path):
    modname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    mod = imp.load_source(modname, path)
    return mod
```

Each of the individual School modules looks like this:

```
class xyz(object):
    def Get_School_Name(self):
        return "xyz"

    def Get_Students(self):
        Students = []
        #code removed for clarity
        #But basically I create a bunch of Student objects
        Student  = {}
        Student['Name'] = "John Smith"
        Student['School'] = "xyz"]
        return Students

    def Get_Student_Details(self):
        # This will return student details
```

At this point I end up with an array that has items like so:

```
{ Name: "John Smith", School: "xyz" }
{ Name: "Bob Jane", School: "abc" }
{ Name: "Jane Davis", School: "xyz" }
... etc
```

What I'd like to do is iterate through this array and then call the Get_Student_Details function for the correct school.  So the first entry in the array should call the Get_Student_Details function in the xyz class, the second in the abc class, the third in the xyz class, passing in the Name parameter each time.

I'm fairly new to Python and not sure how I would go about calling the right class.

Comment: Schools should not each be a new School subclass, they should be instances of School. Also this is tailor-made for a database.

Comment: (shrug) I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but it may be helpful to have a mapping form "School" -> School_Object, rather than the to the school name.

That way in each dictionary you have

{ Name: "John Smith", School: }

Then, you can simply, iterate through the array, access the value associated with the "School" key, and then call get_student_details on the correct class.

Comment: That looks ideal - but how would I "call get_student_details on the correct class"?

Comment: I think he is trying to lazy-load modules; he can't refer to the class until the module is loaded, and he doesn't want to load the module unless it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically call classes within a module with getattr:

```
class_ = getattr(module, 'xyz')
class_().Get_School_Name()
```

I would store the schools in a dictionary instead of a list where the key signifies the school name (assuming you have a single module per school). Then you could do something like this.

```
for student in student_list:
    class_ = getattr(self.Schools[student["School"]], student["School"])
    class_().Get_Student_Details()
```

Remarks:

- You will need to know which schools are in which module though.
- The method Get_Student_Details should be made static as no object information is used (same with Get_Students)
- lower camel case is usually used for function and variable names

Comment: That works - there is one school per module although the school name may be "XYZ School" but the module name is "xyzschool".  Good point about the static